# Run jQuery on JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a AJAX call function assigned to a tab link, which will get the result from a php page and then displayed on the page.

This is the ajax code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".resolved_tab_copy").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"dynamic_tab.php",
        async:true,
         success:function(data){
       $('.main_display_4resolve').html(data);
         }
       });
        console.log("Hello");
    });
 });
```

data retrieved is formatted as HTML element and I want to be able to run jQuery click and various other event on those elements
data retrieved look like following..

```
echo '<div class="ticket_div">
            <div class="menu_wrapper">
                  <div class="resolved_diag_click" id="',$each_issue['issue_id'],'">Notes</div>
                  <div class="resolved_diag_res_click" id="',$each_issue['issue_id'],'">Resources</div>
              </div>
            <div class="resolved_diag_show" id="resolved_notes_displayDiv',$each_issue['issue_id'],'">
                  <div class="resolved_diag_result" id="resolved_diag_resultID',$each_issue['issue_id'],'">';
                  $target_issueid=$each_issue['issue_id'];
                       $diag_list=get_diag_result($target_issueid);

                      foreach($diag_list as $each_diag){
                        echo '<div class="diag_txt">';
                        $name_id=$each_diag['diag_logger'];
                            $name_list=get_name($name_id);
                                foreach($name_list as $each_name){
                                    echo '<div class="resolved_diag_logger">',$each_name['fname'],' ',$each_name['lname'],'</div>';
                                }
                            echo '<div class="resolved_diag_time">',$each_diag['diag_time'],'</div>';
                            echo '<div class="resolved_diag_desc">',$each_diag['diag_desc'],'</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        };


                      echo '<ul class="tkt_ctrl">
                          <li class="resolved_tkt_ctrl_cmnt_click_',$each_issue['issue_status'],'" id="resolved_cmnt_clickid',$each_issue['issue_id'],'" alt="',$each_issue['issue_status'],'">Comment</li>
                           <li class="resolved_tkt_ctrl_li_',$each_issue['issue_status'],'" alt="',$each_issue['issue_status'],'">Email</li>
                           <li class="resolved_tkt_ctrl_resolve_',$each_issue['issue_status'],'" id="resolved_resolveID',$each_issue['issue_id'],'" alt="',$each_issue['issue_status'],'">Resolved</li>
                      </ul>
              </div>
```

i would like to be able to run jQuery event on

```
<div class="resolved_diag_click" and display   <div class="resolved_diag_show".
```

This page when static all jquery works but when retrieved via ajax call jQuery events not working..

I must have missed something very silly I could not get my head around that.. 
if anyone could show me the right direction that would be life saving.. 
Also I am researching on jQuery .on and .live event, is that what we should try..
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, is your `$(".resolved_tab_copy").click(function()` not getting fired?

Comment: Once you converted the response to DOM elements (e.g. by interesting the response into the document), you can bind event handlers as if the elements existed in the document from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery's [.on function](https://api.jquery.com/on/). The elements will have the event listener attached to them even when you create them after page load.

```
$("body").on("click", ".resolved_diag_click", function (e) {
    // handle event here
    alert("foo");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your jquery code have events targeting elements that are not present at the time **(before the ajax)** then you need to say something *i want to target whenever they are present*.

This can happen by either **@Shannon** solution jquery's [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) or if your jquery is *1.6.2 or older* you can use the [.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) (deprecated on **1.7+**)

Use like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#obj").live("click",function() {
   });
});
```

the above is like a normal `.click` event, except that lives even if `#obj` doesnt exist yet and is created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

> if you added element from ajax or dynamically so you must use on method.

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live().

```
 $(document)on(event,selector,function()
{
};
```

**In Your Case**

```
$(document)on("click",".resolved_diag_click",function()
    {
    };
```

[API Documention of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)